# $_REQUET in php's equivalent in python

Tags: php, python, request

I'm following Facebook graph Api dcumentation but there is no python code snippet for verification requests. All code snippets are in PHP. So I need to find the equivalent of **$_REQUEST['hub_verify_token']** in python. i want the below given code to be converted to python

```
$challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
$verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];

if($verify_token==="abc123"){
    echo $challenge;
}

$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: in `flask` it could be `request.args.get('hub_verify_token')` plus `request.form.get('hub_verify_token')` and probably plus `request.cookies.get('hub_verify_token')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django - `request.POST['hub_verify_token']` `request.GET['hub_verify_token']`

Flask - `request.args.get('hub_verify_token')` `request.values.get('hub_verify_token')`